# What is the meaning of this senctence:Excellent answer. Delusions of grandeur. Folks have been institutionalised for less

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can an atheist at least agree that existence is a mystery that is bigger than all of us?                                                       You’ve got it backwards. It’s religious people who try to fill the mysteries of the universe with beliefs based on nothing emprical. Where atheists say “I don’t know” religious people say “It’s God.” Atheists are comfortable with not knowing everything. They know humans are infinitesimal specks in the universe. Religious people think the entire universe was created for and about them. Talk about grandiosity.
Comment:Delusions of grandeur. Folks have been institutionalised for less lol

Comment: Looks like the author is confusing "atheism" and "agnosticism".

Answer (score 1):

"Delusions of grandeur" is a common phrase meaning that something thinks he is much more important than he really is.

A "delusion" is a false belief, especially in the psychiatric sense of someone who has a mental illness that makes him see things that aren't there or believe things that aren't true. Like, "Mr Jones has the delusion that he is Shakespeare".

"Grandeur" means the quality of being grand, that is, greatness.

So "delusions of grandeur" are a false belief that you are great.

"Institutionalized" means put in a hospital for mentally ill people.

So he's saying that religious people have a false belief that they're great because they believe that there is a God who created the universe specifically for them.

(Of course as a Fundamentalist I'd say that it's atheists who have delusions of grandeur, as they refuse to believe in the existence of a being greater than themselves: they insist on believing that they are the most powerful and intelligent beings in the universe. But whatever. :-) )